# Is there a way to have read-and-write views in Range-v3?

Tags: c++11, proxy, rvalue, lvalue, range-v3

In [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) one can easily create view of existing containers. For example

```
#include<range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include<cassert>

int main(){
    std::vector<double> v = {1,2,3};
    auto range = v | ranges::v3::view::transform([](auto x){return x*2;});
    assert( range[1] == 4 );
//    range[1] = 4; // error cannot write to an l-value
}
```

These views are naturally read-only. **I wonder if there is any way to create read and write view within Range-v3?**

I do appreciate that such thing is much more complicated than read-only, and not always possible, but still I wonder if there is a protocol in Range-v3 to use this directly or implement it.

For example, I have seen examples of derived classes from `ranges::view_facade` that implement a member function `read()` (I cannot find the example again, the documentation of Ranges v3 is really scattered around). What about a `write(...)` member function?

I am looking for some hypothetical `bi`directional `transform` code like this:

```
#include<range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include<cassert>

int main(){
    std::vector<double> v = {1,2,3};
    auto range = v | ranges::v3::view::bitransform([](double x){return x*2;}, [](double x){return x/2;}); // direct and inverse function for read and write
    assert( range[1] == 4 );
    range[1] = 8; // error cannot write to an l-value
    assert( range[1] == 8 );
    assert( v[1] == 4 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `transform_view` have elements of proxy type:

```
#include<vector>
#include<range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include<cassert>

struct proxy {
    double& x;
    operator double() { return x*2; }
    void operator=(double y) { x = y / 2; }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<double> v = {1,2,3};
    auto range = v | ranges::v3::view::transform([](auto& x){return proxy{x};});
    assert( range[1] == 4 );
    range[1] = 8;
    assert( range[1] == 8 );
    assert( v[1] == 4 );
}
```

Comment: Of course. Excellent. I am surprised that `void operator=(double y)` doesn't need to be `const`. Given that the proxy will a temporary in this context.